# Assigning Today's Date to a Key and referencing this Key to Add 5 days

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, webdriver-io

I am trying to assign today's date to `contVfrmDate` and use the value/date to increment the next key with x number of days? Can it be done inside an object/dictionary? If yes, how?

```
const ccCustInfo = {
  cropConsultant: 'Test this',
  customerName:   'Customer',
  customerBranch: 'MULBERRY ',
  shippingAddress:'address',
  contractType:   'SKU',
  contVfrom:      'Contract Valid From',
  contVto:        'Contract Valid To',
  internalNotes:  'Internal Notes',
  contVfrmDate:    (new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleString().split(',')[0]),
  contVtoDate:     contVfrmDate.setDate(contVfrmDate.getDate() + 5)
}
```

In the Chrome Console, I see this error.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: contVfrmDate is not defined
at <anonymous>:11:24
```

**Found another simple solution since the `to date` defaults to 8 days out.**

`contVtoDate:     (new Date(Date.now() + (8 /*days*/ * 86400000 /*ms per day*/)).toLocaleString().split(',')[0])}`

```
const ccCustInfo = {
          cropConsultant: 'Test this',
          customerName:   'Customer 5K FARMS',
          customerBranch: 'MULBERRY FL',
          shippingAddress:'3010',
          contractType:   'SKU',
          contVfrom:      'Contract Valid From',
          contVto:        'Contract Valid To',
          internalNotes:  'Internal Notes',
          contVfrmDate:    (new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleString().split(',')[0]),
          contVtoDate:     (new Date(Date.now() + (8 /*days*/ * 86400000 /*ms per day*/)).toLocaleString().split(',')[0])
}
```

Comment: Can you show us how you are trying to access `contVfrmDate` ?

Comment: @Sacha - its in the definition of `contVtodate`

Comment: At this point, before using it in the code, I am testing it in the Chrome console to see if the key: value assignment is even possible. So when I copy/pasted the dict in the console, I got the error mentioned above.

Comment: Can't do self-reflection into the object since it hasn't been created yet. You'll have to manipulate the dates (at least the `frm` date) outside the assignment.

Comment: Okay. Well, if I can get contVfrmDate is not throw an error, then I could use Date to do the + days for contVtoDate.

Comment: Commenting out //contVtoDate:     contVfrmDate.setDate(contVfrmDate.getDate() + 5)` worked.

Comment: Any suggestion on the + X number of days for contVtoDate:?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should realize that adjusting a Date object with `.setDate()` will change the original date. So you need two independent date objects:

```
    const frmDate = new Date();
    const toDate = new Date();
```

But the `toDate` needs 5 days added to it. The most direct way is to now use the `.setDate()` method on `toDate`. Do that by getting the day from `frmDate` and adding your 5 days:

```
toDate.setDate(frmDate.getDate() + 5);
```

The result looks like this:

```js
const frmDate = new Date();
const toDate = new Date()
toDate.setDate(frmDate.getDate() + 5);

const ccCustInfo = {
  cropConsultant: 'Test this',
  customerName:   'Customer',
  customerBranch: 'MULBERRY ',
  shippingAddress:'address',
  contractType:   'SKU',
  contVfrom:      'Contract Valid From',
  contVto:        'Contract Valid To',
  internalNotes:  'Internal Notes',
  contVfrmDate:    frmDate.toLocaleString('en-US',{month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric', year: 'numeric'}),
  contVtoDate:     toDate.toLocaleString('en-US',{month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric', year: 'numeric'})
}
console.log(ccCustInfo);
```

Comment: Based on your answer, I was able to contVtoDate:     (new Date().setDate(new Date(Date.now()).getDate() + 5))` I am trying to figure how to format it mm/dd/yyyy.

Comment: Here is the correct way to format your date: (earlier comment was misleading): `.toLocaleString('en-US',{month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric', year: 'numeric'})`

Comment: I tried to use a get inside the dict/object. For some reason, the date format conversion does not occur.  let test2 = { get contVtoDate() {const frmDate = new Date(); const toDate = new Date(); return toDate.setDate(frmDate.getDate()).toLocaleString(); }}`

Comment: I have no idea what that means, but if you are still trying to access properties that you are creating on that object from within the object definition, **they are not defined yet**. I'm not sure why there is such an instance on convoluting the code so badly. Make things simple - you may be amazed at how easy things are if you simplify them.